# How to provide Cancel option in html5 multi file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, xmlhttprequest

I am devlopening html5 multi file upload where i want to provide cancel option...
but if i call abort event it will abort all the file upload not which i want...
eg. i have file browse button which are calling same controller..on click of cancel option only particular browse button uploading file shoul stop not all the uploading file...

xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

Comment: Ok, you are saying what you don't want. But what do you want? Plz provide more details

Comment: i have added other information...

Comment: I mean it's easier to help you if you show us what code you have so far :) Html, javascript, controller, etc

Answer (score 0):

Call the

`xhr.abort();`

on the cancel event - i.e. clicking the cancel button with `onclick="xhr.abort();"` - assuming of course that the xhr has a global scope.

cheers